# kotlin coroutine val vs fun

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

I'm new learner to coroutine and Kotlin.
Why do I obtain different results, case 1 and 2 below?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    fun a() = async(CommonPool) {
        println("start A")
        delay(1000)
        println("finish A")
    }

    fun b() = async(CommonPool) {
        println("start B")
        delay(1000)
        println("finish B")
    }

    //case 1
    a().await()
    b().await()

    //case 2
    val A = a()
    val B = b()
    A.await()
    B.await()
}
```

Is this val style coding basic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *case 1* is equivalent to

```
val A = a()
await(A)
val B = b()
await(B)
```

That is, you start `A`, await it (here the coroutine suspends), and only then you start `B`, thus `A` and `B` are executed sequentially, not simultaneously.

In *case 2* you start both `A` and `B` and only then the coroutine suspends waiting for `A` and `B`.

Comment: Ah,  OK! now I understand. Thank you for your reply!